pgModeler Layers - How to automatically link to a schema and all its artefacts
I have started using pgModeler (for developing a Postgres database) and find it very convenient however some things are not clear.
How can I set a default layer for a schema instead of having to manually assign it everytime.
Thank you.

I worked around this. I created a template table and duplicate it for every new table I require within the schema. Relationship lines still have to be managed manually however.
